# problem with youtube to mp3 program

Tags: youtube, mp3

I find in web this adress https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/youtube-to-mp3/  and there show when program is free, but in ubuntu software center i have to buy it. why?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the easily usable and amazing `youtube-dl`. You can get it from [here](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

After installing, you can get the audio in mp3 format by using the `-x` switch:

`youtube-dl -x https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ty7mk3UOmo`

Answer (score 0):

The way the Ubuntu Software Center handles free but proprietary (i.e. non Open Source) applications may be a bit confusing. However after we proceed to the download we will see the following:

[image]

So the price we have to pay for this application will be **$ 0.00** which to my understanding is free as in terms of costs.